# Mouse Frozen When Installing Ubuntu Desktop on Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mouse, windows-10

### My Goal:

My goal is to install Ubuntu on my Acer PC and switch from a Windows 10 to Linux.

### What I've Done:

I have already loaded Ubuntu (the distro I chose) onto a USB drive and made it bootable. When I restart my computer with the drive plugged in, my computer loads Ubuntu Desktop.

### The Problem:

Once Ubuntu loads, the cursor freezes and I cannot click the "Try Ubuntu" button, or any button for that matter. The only thing I can do is use my keyboard.

I'd appreciate any answers that will help me solve this or help me understand why this is happening. I have already tried loading Ubuntu multiple times but the cursor is always frozen.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you following the official tutorials to [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)?  Are you verifying the integrity of your download before flashing the ISO to USB? And have you verified the integrity of the flash to make sure that you have valid installation media?  Also consider plugging your mouse into a different port and make sure that you have disabled "fast startup" in Windows power options

Comment: @Nmath I am pretty sure that the IOS image I have downloaded is verified. I am using [this guide](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-install-linux-on-windows-10) for instructions. I don't have a mouse as I have a laptop. I already disabled fast startup and it hasn't helped.

Comment: If you don't want to use gpg or sha256sum to verify, an easier option is to download the Ubuntu **torrent** from "alternative downloads" using your favorite torrent client.  The BitTorrent protocol automatically verifies the integrity of all downloaded files.

Comment: @Nmath Alright, I will make sure the IOS is verified. I don't think it has to do with the touchpad drivers not being loaded because the touchscreen does not work either.

Comment: It can be both.  Touchpad and touchscreen drivers are not universal and often require additional configuration after installation

Comment: @Nmath I downloaded Ubuntu from [this link](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Do I still have to verify?

Comment: Never mind, I installed Ubuntu and used a USB mouse and it works fine now! Thanks!